# getting gps coordinates from zip code php

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-maps, gps

is there a way to get gps coordinates from a zip code in php? for example, I have a mysql table with customers and their address and zip codes, I would like only to use the zip codes to generate the json file with gps coordinates, is something like that possible? After that I would use that json file to show customers on google maps. thanks in advance

Comment: Well, use google to look for a library or a service that offers a mapping of zip codes to location coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

Google offers a geocoding api. Send an http request such as:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=55309&sensor=false
```

Where 55309 is your the desired zipcode.

Then you can parse the xml or json accordingly to get the longitude and latitude.